# Java / Android Garbage Collection of Static private variables

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection

Lets say I have a Fragment defined as such:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
   private static String sample = "";

   public static void setSample(String s) {
      sample = s;
   }
}
```

for the lifetime of the Application, will sample get garbage collected (whether or not any references to MyFragment exist - which shouldn't matter I think)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right that the number of instances of `MyFragment` don't matter.

The `sample` variable will effectively be a GC root for as long as the classloader that loaded `MyFragment` is alive.

It's important to note that *variables* are never garbage collected - *objects* are.

Answer (score 3):

As long as the class is not [unloaded](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/execution.html#12.7), sample variable will not be garbage collected.

> A class or interface may be unloaded if and only if its defining class
>   loader may be reclaimed by the garbage collector as discussed in
>   §12.6. Classes and interfaces loaded by the bootstrap loader may not
>   be unloaded

Answer (score 2):

`private static String sample`

Will begin to exist when it's first referenced in your code (the class loader loads it) and will stay alive independent of the existing object references.